# what is the appropriate regex to extract this kind of field-value string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string with this pattern: `field1:"with space","tag1","tag2" field2:"f1",f2" FooBar1 FooBar2`

How can i extract the fields and convert them to a hash with the property of `hash[:field1] = ["with space", "tag1", "tag2"]`

Comment: What is the criterion to split the value part? Particularly, how is `"f1",f2" FooBar1 FooBar2` supposed to be splitted into an array?

Comment: I just want to extract fields and values. splitting by space doesn't work here(because of space) so I asked about the regex. what is wrong with my question? (to the guys that disvoted the question)

Comment: @Pooya, I can't speak for the down-voters, but the question doesn't say how you want to handle _Foobar1_ and _Foobar2_.

Answer (score 1):

The answer and difficulty of this problem depends on what kind of characters the strings inside the string contain. For the current string, this works:

```
s = 'field1:"with space","tag1","tag2" field2:"f1","f2" FooBar1 FooBar2'
split_string = s.scan(/(\w+):(".*?")\s/)
split_string.map! do |key, string|
  [key, string.delete('"').split(',')]
end
p Hash[split_string]
# => {"field1"=>["with space", "tag1", "tag2"], "field2"=>["f1", "f2"]}
```

The regexp `/(\w+):(".*?")\s` means capture a word followed by a :, then all data between quotes followed by a space.